# How to design normalized relations to store “global/generic” data?

Tags: database-design, normalization, primary-key

### Context

I was designing a relational database model to store data about a company and its production facilities. I had a `facility` relation and many other relations referencing it, most of the time with an identifying relationship.

Here is a simplified extract:

```
-- PostgreSQL
CREATE TABLE facility(
    facility_id integer NOT NULL,
    designation text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_facility PRIMARY KEY (facility_id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_facility UNIQUE (designation)
);
CREATE TABLE facility_description(
    facility_id integer NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_facility_description PRIMARY KEY (facility_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_facility_description_facility FOREIGN KEY (facility_id)
        REFERENCES facility (facility_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE facility_area(
    facility_id integer NOT NULL,
    area_id integer NOT NULL,
    designation text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_facility_area PRIMARY KEY (facility_id, area_id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_facility_area UNIQUE (facility_id, designation),
    CONSTRAINT fk_facility_area_facility FOREIGN KEY (facility_id)
        REFERENCES facility (facility_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Requirements evolved and it was later decided that each facilities would have their own dedicated database. Put it differently, the database would now be specific to a *single* facility.

I could keep the exact same model but it seems like premature pessimization to keep this `facility_id` attribute in the tables since it will always have one single value. So, it would be easy to redesign `facility_area` as `area`:

```
CREATE TABLE area(
    area_id integer NOT NULL,
    designation text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_facility_area PRIMARY KEY (area_id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_facility_area UNIQUE (designation)
);
```

But if I remove `facility_id` from `facility` and `facility_description` then I end up with single-row tables without a primary key, which, I think, does not respect the relational model theory.

```
CREATE TABLE facility(
    designation text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT uq_facility UNIQUE (designation)
);
CREATE TABLE facility_description(
    description text NOT NULL
);
```

Moreover, in this proposal, since there is no foreign key referencing `facility` from `facility_description`, then nothing prevent a description to exist without a corresponding facility, which would have been considered a problem in the initial model.

### Question

So, what is the correct way to store those “global/generic” data such as the designation of the single facility and its optional corresponding description? And by correct I mean by designing relations that respect the Fifth normal form (5NF).

Comment: *"... then I end up with single-row tables without a primary key"* Why without a PK? If the table is to be restricted to a single row, then the (ideal) PK is the empty set (of columns). And I say ideal because no SQL DBMS has implemented such a feature. You can however, in most DBMS, enforce the restriction with a different way. See: [How to limit maximum number of rows in a table to just 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141789/how-to-limit-maximum-number-of-rows-in-a-table-to-just-1/141795#141795)

Comment: I did not know a PK could be the empty set.

Comment: I could indeed keep the initial version of `facility` and `facility_description` by constraining the tables to a maximum of 1 row with constraints on PK `facility_id`. However, it does not feel logical that the other tables would lose their reference to `facility` while the first 2 would keep it.

Comment: Yes, from a constraint point of view, it would make more sense to keep the initial design and the FKs in all tables. If you remove the `facility_id` from the `area` table, nothing forbids a row to be added there while the `facility` table is empty.

Comment: *"I did not know a PK could be the empty set."* It cannot in SQL. But the relational theory allows it I think.

Comment: *"The
<key def>
KEY {} implies that the pertinent relvar can never contain more than one tuple."* Source: Tutorial D, http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/DBE-Chapter11.pdf.
So yes, I think it is allowed.

Comment: *"Yes, from a constraint point of view, it would make more sense to keep the initial design and …"* Good point. So I guess I either keep the original design with a potential performance hit or I need to deviate from the pure relational model.